# Which plural to use if more than one exists?

Tags: word-choice, noun, grammatical-number

I have only studied German for a few weeks. When I use various dictionaries, I noticed that there is a Plural 1 and Plural 2 as can be seen for [*Pizza*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pizza#.C3.9Cbersetzungen) in the table below.

```
          | Singular  | Plural 1   | Plural 2
Nominativ | die Pizza | die Pizzas | die Pizzen
```

Which one is to be used?

Comment: Both are correct. Use the one you prefer.

Comment: Die Nummerierung hat keine Bedeutung derart, dass mal dieser, mal jener richtig ist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are two plural forms of a noun, then *usually* both can be used in German.

It depends on your personal preference which one to use, both will be understood.

Some words in German have even three different plural forms as can be read [here at Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/mehrere-pluralformen). However: not all of them are used equally often.

Here are examples from the link above:

> der Bonus – die Bonus/Bonusse/Boni
>   der Sozius – die Sozien/Sozii/Soziusse
>   das Konto – die Konten/Kontos/Konti
>   das Aroma – die Aromas/Aromen/Aromata

BUT: There are — as was stated by Jan in the comments — also special plural forms which indeed have a different meaning. One can be found in [this wiki article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural) about plural:

*Wort* has two plural forms: *Wörter* in this case stands for the number of words in a sentence (simple count) whereas *Worte* means the real statement made.

Comment: Other example: Das Schild (sign) => Die Schilder, but Der Schild (shield) => Die Schilde. However, that's not one noun that has different plural forms; it's two different nouns that happen to have the same singular spelling.

Answer (score 5):

There aren’t that many words that have two different plural forms. Most of these are loanwords, often from Latin or its descendent languages.

For loanwords, the first stage of loanword incorporation into German is to leave it as it is and to form a plural by simply adding an *s.* (For loanwords that end in *-s*, things get difficult and different.) Thus, *Pizzas* was the earlier way to pluralise *Pizza* in German.

As loanwords get more and more familiar, they are often more formally incorporated into grammar rules. In German, the most typical plural endings of native words are *-e, -er* and *-en* and *Pizza* fits with the *-en* type so *Pizzen* later appeared. Note that neither of these is correct in Italian where *pizze* is the only acceptable plural.

For most of these loanwords with multiple plural forms, it does not matter which form you use. Both *zwei Pizzen* and *zwei Pizzas* are perfectly acceptable and there is no difference between the two. By the way: some dictionaries may note the plurals in a different order; that is often a clear argument for them being equivalent.

Sometimes, even native German words have two different plural forms, and that is where you want to be careful. For example, *Wort* has both the plural *Wörter* and *Worte.* These **cannot** be used interchangeably: *Wörter* signifies a number of letter clusters separated by spaces while *Worte* is a collection of what somebody said.

> Unter den Worten Jesu sticht besonders die Bergpredigt hervor.
>
> Der vorige Satz hat neun Wörter.

As mentioned, this typically only applies to native words, i.e. non-loanwords.

Comment: Actually, *die Pizze* is not uncommon in spoken German (at least among people who know the plural in Italian for one reason or another), either, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's no preference of one over the other.
However it may depend on the region and/or other factors which form is more commonly used.
Looking in older dictionaries, you may often find only one form, where today there are two or even three.
My experience:
The new forms are often seen wrong or "less educated" than the old ones by people who have learned only the "old" form.
Regarding your example "Pizza", the plural "Pizzen" is really used much more regularly by people who are "better educated" - or at least feel so.
"Pizzas", i.e. the very simple way of just adding 's' to get the plural is used by more "simple", but also by more pragmatic persons who just don't care.

It may be different in other regions.

Comment: The older form [should be Pizzas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Pizzas%2C+Pizzen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPizzas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPizzen%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Jan: You're right. This example regarding old and new may be irritating, but regarding "less" and "better" educated it's true - at least among people I know. The thinking of the "Pizzen" users may be "a foreign word can't have such a simple plural form!". I'm wondering if they will ever create a new plural for "Handy" ;-)

Comment: I don’t think *Handy* will ever get a different form … I can’t think of a native word ending in /i/ that one could use as a basis. But maybe I’ll be surprised by language development in a few years ;)

Comment: @Jan *Handys* is a perfectly fine German plural for a word ending in a vowel. The spelling with implied English pronunciation is more anomal and could be normalized ("Hendi" urgh)

Comment: @Chieron Yes, I often write *Händie*. And my point was indeed that I don’t think any *other* form would be likely.